# How to allow user to select an element in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, pywinauto

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now. I'm attempting to find a way to allow a user to select an element on a webpage and to return that element ID.

Either of these two processes would work.

1. The user could click an element to identify the element ID, like with an element selector.
2. The program could display a list of all elements of a certain type like a checkbox, and the user could select which checkbox/text field/button to interact with. I tried to do this with the below code using Selenium, but for some reason this code just returns [] no matter how many checkboxes are on the page.

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#data_configuration_datamaps_ct_fields_body input[type='checkbox']")
print(checkboxes)
```

Every time I find a way to do this, it's with another programming language. When I've tried to ask this in various discords and subreddits, I'm always told to post the specific element I'm trying to work with.

The problem is, I'm trying to do this to develop tools to help my own workflow when doing RPA. So I need a way to select an element at runtime and not to predefine it.

I'm able to do this with other programming languages but have not found a way to do it with Python despite everyone saying Python is ideal for automation.

Is there really no way to accomplish this?

Comment: Generally checkboxes just have xpath //*input[@type='checkbox']. You seem to have an id in there as well. Also you'd want to use it checkboxes[1].click() and so forth. Printing checkboxes generally have no text so [] might be viable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by I have an id in there?

Comment: data_configuration_datamaps_ct_fields_body Might restrict it to just to elements with that id. Trying using print(len(checkboxes)) as well.

Comment: I tested it on this site https://www.jotform.com/form-templates/basketball-league-registration-form-template

And the length is 0 despite there being multiple checkboxes on the site.

Comment: Do you mean the website itself is not able to be read? I tried this site as well and I'm getting no results either.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox